# Duplicate rule doesn't work in production

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

In the sandbox, I created the duplicate rule and matching rule and it works properly. But the same that i was created in production is not working.

1. Sandbox

[image]

2. Production

[image]

Comment: do you have encryption on those fields in PROD?

Comment: @cropredy, Can you please tell me how to check if those fields are encrypted? I couldn't find the Platform Encryption on setup page.

Comment: if you haven't licensed Shield Platform Encryption, you won't find these in Setup